# Paranoid control over packages

Tags: package-management, apt-cache, localrepository

I am new in Ubuntu (come from Slackware).

I would like to install and maintain my system in such a way that I always have available archive of installed packages in the form of `deb` files, starting from the installation CD (also those that I had tried then uninstalled e.g. due to lack of space).

I would like to be able to install any variant of a running system only from local resources.

Can anyone tell me if the system has a tool for this purpose, or a document best describing how to do it manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Maybe [debmirror](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

**Apt already maintains** an 'available archive of installed packages'. It's located at 
 `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Debs are not removed from the archive upon uninstall; they remain in the archive to make reinstall trivial for you. Older versions remain, too. Apt automatically uses cached debs instead of new downloads when possible.

Here's an example: The *first time* I install the `hello` package, apt downloads the package and all the dependencies and stores those debs in the local archive. Then apt tells dpkg to install the packages in the correct order. When I then uninstall the `hello` package, the deb remains in the archive. Finally, the *second time* I install the `hello` package, apt sees that the current version of the package is already in the archive, and uses that instead of downloading.

Just don't run `apt clean`, which will delete the entire archive (only the archive; it does not install or uninstall anything). `apt autoclean` will remove only older versions of debs from the archive, leaving the current versions in place. Consider backing up your archive periodically.